# Function of Inductor in-line with MCU Vdd

Tags: filter, inductor

I've been examining a circuit and have come across something that I have not seen before. The system has a power regulator which outputs a 3V3 signal which is required for certain parts of the circuit. One such component is a \$\mu\$Controller (EFM32G...) which I am relatively familiar with. Now on the IOVDD and AVDD lines, there is an inductor in series with a 1\$\Omega\$ resistor coming from the 3V3 regulator (along with all typical decoupling caps [100nF] and some 'resevoir' caps [10\$\mu\$F]). Below gives a snippet of the circuit diagram.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f23U5m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Can anyone tell me the purpose of L1 in this circuit?**

I am sure it is for some filtering but cannot work it out myself.

Comment: Interestingly, L1 does nothing to decouple IOVDD from AVDD as one might expect. Hence, the designer intended either to decouple the µC from noise on the 3V3 line, or to decouple the 3V3 line from noise produced by the µC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to provide a low-noise supply to sensitive analogue parts of the MCU, such as PLLs or sometimes ADCs.

The supply rail will have a noise put on it by the simultaneous switching of lots of logic gates within the MCU. You may have other ICs nearby producing similar noise. The series inductor attenuates the noise conducted onto the analogue supply, the capacitors decouple it and attenuate the noise further by conducting it to the IC's 0V/GND.

It also stops noise generated by switching analogue circuitry, like PLLs, being conducted onto the supply rail.

Answer (score 0):

It helps with 2 things:

1. lowers inrush current (imagine you plug 3.3V to empty 10uF capacitor, it is practically short for a moment, and your 3.3V source could be damaged)
2. filters some noise that could come from your 3.3V source